# What type of replacement door threshold do I need for a garage service door?

Tags: doors, garage

I'm interested in replacing my old and cracked garage door threshold, but the method it uses to attach is to slide under the already existing plate.

I can't seem to find any existing thresholds that have this property. What should I buy/do to replace the threshold?

[image: Interior View]
[image: Exterior View]
[image: View of Seam]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you have there was built into the door frame as a unit. You wouldn't find that exact part unless you contacted the manufacturer.

I would simply see what your local hardware or home improvement store has on hand. The crest of the curve needs to mate well with your door's bottom seal or sweep. Other than that it's not terribly critical. You'll have to consult your inner engineer and figure it out.

Fit the new threshold to the floor and door plate as necessary. Clear silicone caulk is helpful at the ends and underneath.

Comment: I bought a wood door threshold that appears to fit under the door. (The door + it's sweep mate well with it). I'm guessing that I'll have to screw it into the metal plate then since I probably won't be able to use the same attachment scheme?

Comment: Sure, or through the plate into the floor framing.